# Creating an array of objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, syntax-error

I'm trying to create an array (c++) that consists of 4 objects and I'm using this syntax, something is obviously wrong, but what?

```
for (int octet = 0; octet < 4; octet++) {
        cout << "OCTET NO." << octet << endl;
        cout << "IP:     "; cin >> ip;
        cout << "Subnet: "; cin >> subnet;

        networkOctet[octet] = networkOctet(ip, subnet); //The line where the problem is

        }
```

Thank you for your help!

**!-- UPDATE --!**

Allright, so I changed the code to this but now it says "no matching constructor for initialization of 'networkOctet[4]'"... I have a constructor that is declared, defined and works perfectly on objects that are not in arrays.

Updated code:

```
int ip;

int subnet;

networkOctet networkOctetObject[4];

for (int octet = 0; octet < 4; octet++) {
    cout << "OCTET NO." << octet << endl;
    cout << "IP:     "; cin >> ip;
    cout << "Subnet: "; cin >> subnet;
    if (octet == 3) {
        networkOctetObject[octet] = networkOctet(ip, subnet, true);
    }
    else {
        networkOctetObject[octet] = networkOctet(ip, subnet, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change one of the `networkOctet` to something like `getNetworkOctet`

Comment: I'm assuming `networkOctet` is the class name. You can't use class name as an array variable

Comment: Declareation of networkOctet?

Comment: Something that overloads [] and ()?

Comment: this question is like a really bad trick question...... is that an array variable name?  is that a class name?  is it something with [] and () overloaded?  is it a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you overloaded both `[]` and `()` on a type `decltype(networkOctet)`, so the problem is that you're treating the name as both a variable `networkOctet[octet]` and a type `networkOctet(ip, subnet)`. If your variable of type `X[4]` is named `y`, you'd use the following syntax to make this work:

```
y[octet] = X(ip, subnet);
```

where `y` itself is declared as `X y[4]`.

Comment: Allright, so I changed the code to this but now it says "no matching constructor for initialization of 'networkOctet[4]'"... I have a constructor that is declared, defined and works perfectly on objects that are not in arrays. @LuchianGrigore

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor is it a default constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You can only create an array of types that do have a default constructor. If you defined your own constructor and did not add a default constructor then you cannot create an array of this type because the compiler tries to value-initializes all elements (using the default constructor) in the array when the array is created. If you drop the default constructor the elements in the array cannot be value-initialized (because there is no default constructor) and your mentioned compiler error appears.

When the compiler sees the line

```
networkOctet networkOctetObject[4];
```

it tries to create 4 objects of type `networkOctet`. To create those objects a constructor of `networkOctet` must be called. As you create an array the compiler tries to call the default constructor that is not available. This is the line where the error occures. So to make your code work add a default constructor by adding

```
networkOctet() {
    // Initialize a networkOctet to a valid default value
}
```

to your `networkOctet` class (notice that this default constructor must be `public`).